# ImportXML method of Access class library failing

Tags: .net, ms-access, office-interop

[edit]
I believe it's because the file was about 1.5gb Access gave up the ghost and fell over, but re-opening it performed a cleanup and it sorted itself out. It didn't reach it's row limit so I guess the answer is to frequently close/open the file to flush itself out? Leaving this open in case there's a better answer
[/edit]

I've inherited some code that works as it's been going for a few years now :)

Basically it opens an access database, loops a number of xml files and uses the importXML method to append data to a number of tables.

After about half way through (there's a few thousand xml files) it just stops, the error is pretty generic and says it failed to import a file and to consult the access database errors table it created.

Except the error table is empty.

If I open Access and manually import the file it had trouble with, or kick-start the program again it just works.

Is there a way to get more information on the error from the Access object, or does anyone know if there's any known issues or workarounds like memory problems, etc.

thanks.

```
    Dim oAccess As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application
    oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(dbfile, True)

    Try
        For Each xmlfile In MyXmlFiles
            oAccess.ImportXML(xmlfile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcImportXMLOption.acAppendData)
            Dim xmlFileInfo7 As New System.IO.FileInfo(xmlfile)
            xmlFileInfo7.Delete()
        Next

    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("Error at, " & xmlfile & vbCr & e.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: How large is the dataset you're importing? Note that Access has a 2GB size limit on the database, and transactional import operations (including `ImportXML`) use quite a bit of space. I wouldn't be surprised if you'd need to compact the database every few hundred files.

Comment: Ah, see you've found out yourself. Compacting likely is the way to go, I guess you know how to compact the database using interop?

Comment: Run .CompactRepair?, but it needs parameters, I did code a close then open until I saw your post but don't know simpler way

Comment: Close current database, choose file name for new copy, use either .CompactRepair or .DBEngine.Compact to compact the database into a new temporary file, delete current file, rename copy to name of current file. Access itself uses _Database.mdb_ as the name of the temporary file, in the same folder as the actual database, _Database1.mdb_ if that already exists, etc, even for .accdb files. In my experience .DBEngine.Compact is less error-prone than .CompactRepair.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for a simple way to compact without all the fannying on of repairing to a new file then renaming back, I guess not. Thanks for your help though, I'll code it like you said, but it's ok with accdb?

Comment: Yeah ofc, it's more a note that Access does the same and is not picky about the extension of the copy (or cleaning up the copy if the compact fails), so you don't need to be either. So even if you were to automate pressing the _Compact & Repair_ button in Access (I strongly recommend you don't), you'd still essentially be doing the same steps.